# babel configurations for code sandbox for react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, deployment, babeljs

- I am trying to implement web workers in a redux app
- so I took the below example and implement in tyhe sandbox
  https://github.com/ardi-n/react-redux-web-workers-sample-app
- for this they are using babel
- so I took a working babel code sandbox which had the below configurations.

  `{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
          "decoratorsBeforeExport": false
        }
      ]
    ]
  }`
- but the app had this configurations

  `{
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-es2015-destructuring",
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }`
- when I replaced the configurations, I was getting the below errors.
- so I researched and got this link
  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files/
- I installed this two dependencies too @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring and babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring
- but still I am facing the issues.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kt3kparcel-babel7-decorators-example-l9wxk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add correct dependecies. And learn tools that you are using(npm, babel)

https://codesandbox.io/s/kt3kparcel-babel7-decorators-example-lgn78

Comment: hey but in this demo I see data loading https://ardi-n.github.io/react-redux-web-workers-sample-app/dist/index2.html, why I am not seeing in our code sandbox :( and can you let me know what dependencies you installed :(

Comment: @Talget hey I added webworkers in this code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-web-workers-sample-app-yfh93 can you help me